# How to type an object that references to itself but also allows other values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, nested, circular-dependency

I want to type the following nested object. the type works when you assign it to an object, but is there a way to make it work while accessing its properties?

```
type NestedObject = {
   [key: string]: NestedObject | string;
}

const obj: NestedObject = {
  a: '123',
  b: {
    b_a: {
      b_a_a: '456'
    },
    b_b: '789'
  }
};

function ABC(myNestedObject: NestedObject) {
    const nestedObject: NestedObject = {
      // Property 'fail' does not exist on type 'string | NestedObject'.
      'failProperty': myNestedObject.properties.fail 
    };
}
```

I tried to make it conditional by checking whether it extends from string,
but I'm having challenges accessing the current value for the specified key. This for instance, doesn't work:

```
type NestedObject = {
  [K in NestedObject]: NestedObject[K] extends string ? string : NestedObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow down whether the `.properties` property is a string or a NestedObject. If it's a string, then referencing `myNestedObject.properties.fail` would result in problems - which is why TypeScript is warning you about it.

Construct the code paths so that if the typeof results in `string`, you don't reference `myNestedObject.properties.fail`.

```
function ABC(myNestedObject: NestedObject) {
    if (typeof myNestedObject.properties === 'string') {
        throw new Error();
    }
    const nestedObject: NestedObject = {
      // Property 'fail' does not exist on type 'string | NestedObject'.
      'failProperty': myNestedObject.properties.fail 
    };
}
```

Comment: It works, but what if I have multiple properties? I'd have to check for all of them

Comment: Right - that'd be the only way to be type-safe, to check that every property is either a string or nested object before being able to use them as such.